# Trying to Create a List of Dictionaries From Web-Scraped Content

Tags: python

I'm new to Python but have worked in R for a while but am mostly used to working with data frames. I web-scraped the following for which the output is four lists included below: but with values taken out to create a minimal reproducible example.

I am trying to put these into a list of dictionaries such that the data is set up in the following way.

```
Each dictionary, rankings[i], should have these keys:

rankings[i]['name']: The name of the restaurant, a string.
rankings[i]['stars']: The star rating, as a string, e.g., '4.5', '4.0'
rankings[i]['numrevs']: The number of reviews, as an integer.
rankings[i]['price']: The price range, as dollar signs, e.g., '$', '$$', '$$$', or '$$$$'.
```

I get so confused by dictionaries within lists and sequences of sequences in general, so if you have any great resources, please link them here! I've been reading through Think Python.

This is what I have, but it ends up returning one dictionary with lists of values, which is not what I need.

Thanks much!

```
def Convert(tup, di): 
    for w, x,y,z in tup: 
        di.setdefault(w, []).extend((w,x,y,z))
    return di 
yelp = list(zip(name, stars, numrevs, price))
dictionary = {} 

output = Convert(yelp, dictionary)

#data
name = ['Mary Mac’s Tea Room', 'Busy Bee Cafe', 'Richards’ Southern Fried']

stars = ['4.0 ', '4.0 ', '4.0']

numrevs = ['80', '49', '549']

price = ['$$', '$$', '$$']
```

```
Update:

This will give me a dictionary of a single restaurant:
```

def Convert(tup, di):
dictionary = {}
for name, stars, numrevs, price in tup:
yelp = list(zip(name, stars, numrevs, price))

```
name, stars, numrevs, price = tup[0]
entry = {"name"   : name,
     "stars"  : stars,
     "numrevs": numrevs,
     "print"  : price}
return entry
```

output = Convert(yelp, dictionary)
output

```
This is my attempt to iterate over the all restaurants and add them to a list. It looks like I am only getting the final restaurant and everything else is being written over. Perhaps I need to do something like
```

def Convert(tup, di):
dictionary = {}

```
for name, stars, numrevs, price in tup: 
    yelp = list(zip(name, stars, numrevs, price))
    
for i in name, stars, numrevs, price:
    l = []
    entry = {"name"   : name,
         "stars"  : stars,
         "numrevs": numrevs,
         "price"  : price}
    l.append(entry)
return l
```

output = Convert(yelp, dictionary)
output

Comment: Why do you want a list of dicts? If you just want a list of restaurants where each element contains all the info about a restaurant, more natural is to define a Restaurant class and then make a list of Restaurant objects. Alternatively, if you want to be able to look up the restaurants by name, then a single dict makes sense, where keys are names and values are tuples (stars, numrevs, price).

Comment: Thanks, @Burrito. That's good information to know. I'm not sure why particularly the teacher wants it in this format, but perhaps just for the sake of manipulating the data and getting a better understanding of data structures. I'd imagine I'll mostly be working out of pandas (given it's similarity to R), but I also do think it's good for me to really gain a better understanding for how all of this comes together.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in your function that attempts to build a list of dicts in the format you want.  You make each value with the `extend` method.  This adds to a list; it does not contrsuct a dict.

Start from the inside: build a single dict in the format you want, from only the first set of elements.  Also, use meaningful variable names -- do you expect everyone else to learn your one-letter mappings, so you can save a few seconds of typing?

```
name, stars, numrevs, price = tup[0]
entry = {"name"   : name,
         "stars"  : stars,
         "numrevs": numrevs,
         "print"  : price}
```

*That* is how you make a single dict for your list of dicts.
That should get you started.  Now you need to (1) learn to add `entry` to a list; (2) iterate through *all* of the quadruples in `tup` (another meaningless name to replace) so that you end up adding each entry to the final list, which you return.

---

Update for second question:

It keeps overwriting because you explicitly tell it to do so.  Every time through the loop, you reset `l` to an empty list.  *Stop that*!  There are plenty of places that show you how to accumulate iteration results in a list.  Start by lifting the initialization to *before* the loop.

```
l = []
for ...
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, so I am getting an error that the tupple isn't defined. Could I just put them into tupples using something like; ```def extract(items): 
    for each_restaurant, each_review, each_numrevs, each_price in zip(restaurant, reviews, numrevs, price):
        print(each_review, each_numrevs, each_price in zip(restaurant, reviews, numrevs, price)```

Comment: Code updates have to go into your question, since comments lose the indentations.
Also, do not ask whether something will work: if you want to know, try it out.

Comment: The tuple is undefined because your original code is out of order.  Fix that, and you'll have a valid `tup` value in your function.

Comment: I'm a bit confused...from your response, it sounds like I should remove the "extend" part of the function. When you say it is out of order, are you referring to "dictionary" not being at the top of the function?

Comment: Yes, that's what I said: `extend` is a list operation, and you say that you're trying to produce a `dict` at that point.

Comment: Your mis-ordered code is in your main program: the code you posted fails to run, because of the undefined symbols in your `zip` call.

Comment: Thanks, so I think I have it for one dictionary and have attempted to iterate, but it seems to be writing over all values. Should I be using something other than append() here to save it to a list? I've updated the question.